# "On the forecast" vs. "In the forecast"

Tags: prepositions

Which usage is correct?

1. This is shown in/on the forecast.
2. The numbers are in/on the forecast.

Answer (score 3):

You would usually use "**in** the forecast"

"In the forecast" means that the forecast has predicted some results(/outcome/event) and you are talking about what the results are.

The only time you might use "on the forecast" is if you meant "the forecast" to be a TV show or other media. For example, if you had watched the weather forecast on TV, you might say "I saw on the (weather) forecast that it will rain".

This is a similar construct to other TV shows: "I saw it on Eastenders yesterday" but using "the forecast" to mean a specific TV show or segment of a TV show with revolves solely around a forecast of some type.

Comment: “On the forecast” might also be used if pointing at a chart of future sales predictions or similar. Basically when there is something tangible where the forecast can be found.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding this usage, would we also use "on the forecast" when we are trying to explain what a graph shows? That is when we are explaining something physical or tangible like a graph.